# Может ли hibernate помочь в добавлении/обновлении строки по ключу/ключам

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Добрый день 
Есть сущность Example  с полями: id, name, type, values..

Требуется найти строчку по ключу name, type и обновить значения values. 
Если такой строчки не обнаружено, то вставить новую. 
Констрейн (name, type) присутствует. Многопоточность.

Я могу организовать обновление/ добавление строки отдельными транзакциями, с блокировкой записи и т.д., но может в  hibernate это уже реализовано( к примеру, merge)?

Comment: Это реализовано в любой ORM.

Comment: Merge? Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Все что вы перечислили - добавление, обновление, транзакции и пр.

Comment: Я понимаю, что реализованно. Мне не понятно, если я в двух разных  транзакцях обнаружу, что отсутвует запись с ключом и добавлю одинаковый ключ, то в конце одной из транзакций сработает констрейн. Я же хочу, чтобы одна транзакция выполнила insert, другая update. Может ли hibernate помочь с таой реализацие или разраб сам должен позаботится об этом?

Comment: вы можете настроить уровни изоляции. А в целом это ваша ответственность предотвращать или разрешать подобные ситуации.

Comment: Может быть пример?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да в JPA и HIBERNATE есть метод merge, в который передается неперсистный entity. Метод обращается в БД для поиска данного объекта. Если объект в БД уже есть, то метод возвращает персистный entity, который учитывает состяние в БД и новое (которое было передано в метод). Если объекта в БД нет, то метод возвращает новый персистный entity на основе состояния, которое было передано в метод.
В этом смысле проблема автоматизации решена. 
Однако проблема синхронизации на уровне транзакций не решена. Например, в первой транзакции метод покажет, что объекта еще нет, но транзакцию применит через час, а тем временем вторая сессия добавит объект в БД.
Возможно, использование кэша второго уровня позволит решить вопрос синхронизации двух сессий.

Comment: Спасибо, !! Я думаю вопрос можно снять , так как моя система может состоять из нескольких виртуальных машин java ....